# Change font of footnotesized texts

Tags: fonts, macros

I am trying to redefine the footnotesize command to be displayed in another font than the rest of the document's Computer Modern. Specifically the font `libertine`. However I find it tricky. Can someone help me?

Here is the unaltered `\footnotesize` code:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249415/set-font-size-for-footnotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out what LaTeX thinks the Libertine font is called:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\rmdefault
\end{document}
```

Upon compiling this test, you'll discover that the internal name is

> LinuxLibertineT-TLF

Fine, now we can patch `\footnotesize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd{\footnotesize}
  {\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}\selectfont} % choose Libertine before typesetting
  {}{}

\setlength{\textheight}{1cm} % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

This is some text in the default
font\footnote{This is a footnote in Linux Libertine}

\end{document}
```

Be careful that not only footnotes would be typeset in Libertine, but everything in the scope of a `\footnotesize` declaration.

[image]

On the other hand, now that you see the output, you are likely to go back and remove the `\apptocmd` instruction. `;-)`

Comment: The font is not changing back to cmr after initiating a \footnotesize. I have to manually add \fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont after each \footnotesize. Is there a workaround for this as well?

Comment: @E.l4d3 How do you initiate a `\footnotesize`? If I do `aaa {\footnotesize bbb ccc} ddd`, then `aaa` and `ddd` are in the same font.

Comment: Usually without encapsulating {}. It indeed works when doing so, thank you!

Comment: @E.l4d3 That's the best way (but remember `\par` before `}` if the `\footnotesize` text is a full paragraph. By the way, LaTeX has `\normalfont` and `\normalsize` to restore the initial fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load `libertine` and restore the previous font after that, then you just have to patch-in the `\libertine`<sup>1</sup> command provided by the package into the `\footnotesize` command. I chose to use `\g@addto@macro` instead of completely redefining `\footnotesize` so that the patch (theoretically) doesn't depend on the class or font size being used.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % Just for the example

\let\saverm\rmdefault % \
\let\savesf\sfdefault % | Save the current font
\let\savett\ttdefault % /
\usepackage{libertine} % Load libertine
\let\rmdefault\saverm % \
\let\sfdefault\savesf % | Restore the font
\let\ttdefault\savett % /

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % For dummy text

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\footnotesize\libertine % <--- Patching \libertine in
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For people that want to use this with other fonts: not all packages define a command to change the font like `libertine` does, so it may not be *that* easy, but it's certainly doable.

Comment: Thank you. A preferable solution if I don't want to redefine footnotesize for another project.