# footnote pointing to same reference when are references (style=verbose-inote and footmisc)

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, footmisc

I was wondering if there is the option that a same reference do not need to be repeated as a new entrance in the footnote and put directly the number of the previous one. Also, if it is possible avoid the Ibid and point to the former reference directly ]. See example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[margin=15mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\makeatletter
\def\TPT@doparanotes{\par
   \prevdepth\z@ \TPT@hsize
   \TPTnoteSettings
   \parindent\z@ \pretolerance 8
   \linepenalty 200
   \renewcommand\item[1][]{\relax\ifhmode \begingroup
       \unskip
       \advance\hsize 10em % \hsize is scratch register, based on real hsize
       \penalty -45 \hskip\z@\@plus\hsize \penalty-19
       \hskip .15\hsize \penalty 9999 \hskip-.15\hsize
       \hskip .01\hsize\@plus-\hsize\@minus.01\hsize 
       \hskip 6em\@plus .3em
              %%%%%
      \endgroup\fi
      \tnote{##1}\,\ignorespaces}%
   \let\TPToverlap\relax
   \def\endtablenotes{\par}%
}


\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
  \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
  #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[stable,para,hang]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\footglue=.1em plus.15em minus.15em

\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
  \@makefnmark\nobreak
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
% HotFix from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300259/84485
% Version1 of titlesec is not compatible with the latest texlive. 
% Either the titlesec package must be updated, or the following HotFix used:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,maxcitenames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[r]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}




\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{soul} % for smarter (word-wrapping) underlining
\setul{1pt}{.4pt} % 1pt below contents
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{[\textbf{TODO:} #1]}}}
% \titlespacing\section{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8bp}{1em}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\autocite} % citations in footnotes
\bibliography{Mendeley,Zotero}

\headheight=14pt

% Explicitly set footnote font size to match call (i.e., 8pt).
% Taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249422/84485
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{8}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={H2020-MSCA-IF-2018},    % title
    pdfauthor={},
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
  }



\begin{document}

lolo \cite{Acedo2019PlaceEngagement} toe\cite{Funck2004DeterminingImages} caca\cite{Acedo2019PlaceEngagement} lili\cite{Acedo2019PlaceEngagement}


\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible that footnotes marks 3 and 4 disappear and point to 1 since is the same reference?

Thanks

Comment: This is tricky and I would generally try to avoid it, but there are many questions about styles like this on this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864. The last one would be a *very* strong candidate for a duplicate.

Comment: Any news here? Did https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864 work? If not, can you please update your question with what you tried and how it did not work for you?