# How to change the font size of the footnote-mark?

Tags: footnotes

How can I change the font size of the footnote "mark"? I mean the number that appears after a word in text and later in the footer.
I know how to use different ways to change the footnote "Text" size, but the marker seems to remain the same.

I tried, for example
`{\tiny \footnote{This is my footnote.}}`

I also tried
`{\tiny \footnotemark{200}}`

But there is no change. Only the text part changes the font size.
The marker in text and in the footnote part remains quite large in my case, and looks bad.

I use the Annales latex package. https://gitlab.utu.fi/samnuutt/annales

```
\documentclass{annales}

% NOTE: quite a bunch of other packages are loaded through annales class already, so these are just an example of what one might also need
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}



%%%
%%% set author, title, subtitle, ISBNs here
%%%
% if you dont have a subtitle an \mbox{} will do just fine
\makeatletter
\author{M}\let\Author\@author
%\authorx{Stone, Maria B}\let\Authorx\@authorx
\title{Title}\let\Title\@title
\subtitle{A}\let\Stitle\@subtitle
\isbnprint{XXX-XXX-XX-XXXX-X}\let\Isbnprint\@isbnprint
\isbnweb{XXX-XXX-XX-XXXX-X}\let\Isbnweb\@isbnweb
\issnprint{XXX-XXX-XX-YYYY-Y}\let\Issnprint\@issnprint
\issnweb{XXX-XXX-XX-ZZZZ-Z}\let\Issnweb\@issnweb
\printedat{Printhouse, Turku, Finland, 2023}\let\Printedat\@printedat
\makeatother

% set language: \finfalse for english \fintrue for finnish
\finfalse

% set PDF information for PDF/A
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={\Author},
  pdftitle={\Title},
  pdfsubtitle={\Stitle},
  pdfsubject={Dissertation},
  pdfkeywords={Some;Key;Words;Here},
  pdfissn={\Issnprint},
  pdfeissn={\Issnweb},
  pdfisbn={\Isbnprint},
  pdfdisplaydoctitle,
  keeppdfinfo, % without this author, keywords, etc. found only in XMP
  colorlinks=false,
  linkbordercolor={white},
  citebordercolor={white},
  unicode,
  pdfapart=1,
  pdfaconformance=B,
  pdfrendition={screen},
}
\iffin
\hypersetup{
  pdflang={fi-FI}
}
\else
\hypersetup{
  pdflang={en-GB}
}
\fi

%%%
%%% main document starts here
%%%
\begin{document}
% to use hyperref to just set PDF information uncomment below
%\begin{NoHyper}



This is a test sentence.{\tiny \footnotemark[1]} 

{\tiny \footnotetext[1]{In this text, I try to describe my research work from the past many years.}}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% if you used HoHyper at the beginning uncomment below as well
% \end{NoHyper}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set font size for footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249415/set-font-size-for-footnotes)

Comment: No, because in the link/question "Set font size for footnotes", I only see examples on how to change the text font size, but not the "superscript"/"marker" size. Could you please specify specifically which command you think is going ot change the "marker" size?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: With KOMA-Script classes you can use `\deffootnote` and `\deffootnotemark`. With the standard classes you could use package `scrextend` to get the same feature.

Comment: As mentioned, you should provide a Minimal Working Example including your `documentclass`. Its also possible to patch the footnote macro without additional packages, but that also needs further Info's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's dig it out... the `annales` style seems not to touch any definition for the footnotes, and uses the `book` class. Let's find where the footnote mark is printed. From a UNIX shell prompt:

```
bash[romano:~/tmp] % latexdef -c book footnote

\footnote:
macro:->\@ifnextchar [\@xfootnote {\stepcounter \@mpfn \protected@xdef \@thefnmark {\thempfn }\@footnotemark \@footnotetext }

[romano:~/tmp] % latexdef -c book @footnotemark

\@footnotemark:
macro:->\leavevmode \ifhmode \edef \@x@sf {\the \spacefactor }\nobreak \fi \@makefnmark \ifhmode \spacefactor \@x@sf \fi \relax 

[romano:~/tmp] % latexdef -c book @makefnmark  

\@makefnmark:
macro:->\hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont \@thefnmark }}
```

Hmmm... so maybe changing the last one will work?

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Text with a footnote\footnote{footnote here}
\end{document}
```

Bingo!:

[image]

...

[image]

I used the `\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont` to make it more visible, but you can use `\tiny` there.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented this suggestion and it worked.